# does not contain a constructor that takes 3 arguments

Tags: c#, constructor

please bear with me as I'm just learning C#. Just messing around with C# I decided to come up with an inventory system to test out but I have one problem in my script:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;


public class Item
{
    public String name;
    public int pesos;

    public int getPesos()
    {
        return pesos;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
public class statuseffect
{
    statuseffect(string Effect,int Amount,int Duration)
    {
        string effect = Effect;
        int amount = Amount;
        int duration = Duration;
    }
}
public class Potion : Item 
{
    public int hpeffect;
    public int mpeffect;
    List<statuseffect> effects = new List<statuseffect>();


    public Potion(int hp,int mp)
    {
        hpeffect = hp;
        mpeffect = mp;
    }
    public void addEffect(statuseffect eff)
    {
        effects.Add(eff);
    }
}
class game
{
public static void Main()
    {   
        Potion healthPotion = new Potion(200,50);
        healthPotion.pesos = 23;
        Console.WriteLine(healthPotion.hpeffect);
        statuseffect slow = new statuseffect("slow",10,30);
    }
}
```

in the last line the compiler tells me that statuseffect does not contain a constructor that takes 3 arguments. From what I can tell, it does contain 3 arguments. Is there something I am missing here?

as a side note. if you guys have any comments or suggestions for my script, that would be helpful as well.

Comment: If you're just starting to program, I eager you to stick to strict naming conventions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0(v=vs.71).aspx (now your methods begin with lower case, so does statuseffect class, public class variables shouldn't be fiels - make them as properties, whitespace also matters)

Comment: You must start reading a good book on C# and OOP

Comment: yeah this is my second day on C# so I still have a lot to learn. Any book suggestions are welcome.

Comment: normally students learn oop concepts in C++, however if you are learning OOP and using C# language then "Professional C# by WROX" is best

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your constructor is `private` and therefore "invisible" to code outside the class itself. Try adding the keyword `internal` before the constructor. Or, if it needs to be visible from other projects as well, add `public` instead.

Another issue: In your class `statuseffect`, you declare three **local** variable inside your constructor. Those variable's only scope is the constructor. You must move their declarations out of the constructor (then they become instance **fields** of the class). The constructor can still assign to them.

Answer (score 2):

Your constructor needs to be marked `public`.

Comment: oh duh....man i didn't even notice til now. It's those small details that get you.

Answer (score 2):

As `c#` is specifically an Objectt oriented language so every thing you declare in a class without an access specifier it is regarded as private by the compiler. So declare your constructor `public`, that will solve the case

```
public statuseffect(string Effect,int Amount,int Duration)
    {
        string effect = Effect;
        int amount = Amount;
        int duration = Duration;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your constructor public. When you dont specify any access-specifier by default it becomes private, means it can only be used inside your class. Making it public makes it accessible from outside.

```
public class statuseffect
{
  public statuseffect(string Effect,int Amount,int Duration)
  {
    string effect = Effect;
    int amount = Amount;
    int duration = Duration;
  }
}
```

Moreover do something with those variables, they are of no use.

Comment: I wouldn't say the rest is all good. Look at the class here. It only has a constructor that declares local variables of no use. See newest version of my answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void Populare_Books()
{
    Books[] bks = { new Books(1, "Shogun", "James Clavell"), new Books(2, "Pe aripile vantului", "Margaret Mitchell"), new Books(3, "MANDRIE SI PREJUDECATA", "Jane Austen"), new Books(4, "ANNA KARENINA", " Lev Tolstoi"), new Books(5, "Notre-Dame de Paris", "Victor Hugo"), new Books(6, "Marile speranțe", "Charles Dickens"), new Books(7, "Ion", "Liviu Rebreanu"), new Books(8, "Cărțile junglei", "Rudyard Kipling")};
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("DataSource=localhost; UserID=root;database=" + nume);
    con.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Books (BookID, Title, ISBN, Number, NumberLeft) VALUES (@BookID, (@Title, (@ISBN, (@Number, (@NumberLeft)";
    MySqlTransaction tra = con.BeginTransaction();
    try
    {
        cmd.Transaction = tra;
        foreach (Books bo in bks)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookID", bo.BookID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", bo.Title);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ISBN", bo.ISBN);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Number", bo.Number);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumberLeft", bo.NumberLeft);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        }
        tra.Commit();
        Console.WriteLine("Tabelul Books a fost umplut");
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        tra.Rollback();
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```